# Partition a predicate by "OR" logic in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, logic

How to partition a predicate into several predicates based on the logic ***OR ( || )***? The evaluation of the resulting predicates would be same as the input predicate. The resulting predicates must not contain logic ***OR ( || )***. 
Any idea/algorithm/java/pseudo code would be helpful.

Sample input outputs:-

```
Input:  a>b || p>q
Output: a>b, p>q

Input: (a>b || p>q) && x>y
Output: (a>b && x>y), (p<q && x>y)

Input: (a>b || p>q) && (x>y || r>s)
Output: (a>b && x>y), (a>b && r>s), (p>q && x>y), (p>q && r>s)

Input: (a>b || p>q) && (x>y && r>s)
Output: (a>b && x>y && r>s), (p>q && x>y && r>s)

Input: (a>b || p>q) && (x>y && (r>s || m>n))
Output: (a>b && x>y && r>s),(a>b && x>y && m>n),(p>q && x>y && r>s),(p>q && x>y && m>n)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the pattern you want to follow, is it changing every `||` to `&&`? because I cannot find shared pattern among your examples

Comment: @Yahya it is simply pushing all of the `||` up to the top level. Substitute `s/, / || /` in the examples.

Comment: It reduces OR logics from the predicate. If the evaluation of the input predicate is true then the evaluation of the output predicates are also true.

Comment: *Parse* the input string into a [binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree), then split that tree for every `||` node you have.

Comment: @Andreas I am following that direction, but I am stuck in somewhere in the merge. The idea is cutting the tree after the node with '||' and then merging one of them each time.

Comment: What are `a` and `b` , I would like to know the is the input, is it a String ? and is the output a String as well?

Comment: @Yahya assume these are integer variables. Although, the variable type has nothing to do with the problem. Anyway, the predicate is in String format. Imagine the predicate is in the "if" statement. If I understood your question.

Comment: @arefinsami so the input/expression is a String that you wanna change it to another String that obey the rule you mentioned

Comment: @Yahya, you are right.

Comment: You can basically replace each inequality with a variable, replace || by + and && by * . Now all the normal mathematical rules are true and you want to convert the equation to the form (... * ... * ...) + (... * ... * ...) + ..., e.g. (a || b) && c ==> (a + b) * c = a * c + b * c ==> (a && c) || (b && c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You parse input, e.g. `(a>b || p>q) && (x>y && (r>s || m>n))`, into a binary expression tree.

```
           &&
    ||              &&
 >      >      >          ||
a b    p q    x y      >      >
                      r s    m n
```

Then you locate a `||` node and clone the tree twice, replacing the `||` node with each side of the node.

```
       &&                              &&
 >           &&                   >           &&
a b     >          ||            p q     >          ||
       x y      >      >                x y      >      >
               r s    m n                       r s    m n
```

Then you do it again, and again, until all `||` are eliminated.

```
      &&                      &&                      &&                      &&
 >         &&            >         &&            >         &&            >         &&
a b     >      >        p q     >      >        a b     >      >        p q     >      >
       x y    r s              x y    r s              x y    m n              x y    m n
```

Finally, you print the result.

```
a>b && (x>y && r>s)
p>q && (x>y && r>s)
a>b && (x>y && m>n)
p>q && (x>y && m>n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript function that recursively parses input then multiplies terms:

```
function parsePredicateIntoBinaryTree(predicate) {
    function trimParen(a) {
        return a.trim().replace(/^\(*/, '').replace(/\)*$/, '').trim();
    }
    function multiplyTerms(s, t) {
        return s.reduce(function (c, a) {
            t.forEach(function (b) {
                c.push(a.trim() + ' && ' + b.trim())
            });
            return c;
        }, []);
    }
    predicate = trimParen(predicate);
    var firstAmp = predicate.indexOf('&&')
    var leftTerm = predicate.substring(0, firstAmp);
    var rightTerm = predicate.substring(firstAmp + 2);
    var leftLeaf = leftTerm.indexOf('&&') < 0;
    var rightLeaf = rightTerm.indexOf('&&') < 0;
    if(leftLeaf && rightLeaf)
    {
        var a = trimParen(leftTerm).split('||');
        var b = trimParen(rightTerm).split('||');
        return multiplyTerms(a, b);
    }
    else if(leftLeaf && !rightLeaf)
    {
        var a = trimParen(leftTerm).split('||');
        var b = parsePredicateIntoBinaryTree(rightTerm);
        return multiplyTerms(a, b);
    }
    else if(!leftLeaf && rightLeaf)
    {
        var a = parsePredicateIntoBinaryTree(leftTerm);
        var b = trimParen(rightTerm).split('||');
        return multiplyTerms(a, b);
    }
    else if(!leftLeaf && !rightLeaf)
    {
        var a = parsePredicateIntoBinaryTree(leftTerm);
        var b = parsePredicateIntoBinaryTree(rightTerm);
        return multiplyTerms(a, b);
    }
}
function parsePredicate(predicate){
    console.log('Input:  ' + predicate);
    console.log('Output:  (' + parsePredicateIntoBinaryTree(predicate).join('),(') + ')');
}

parsePredicate('(a>b || p>q && (z<h || y>=e)) && (x>y && (r>s || m>n))');

Input:  (a>b || p>q && (z<h || y>=e)) && (x>y && (r>s || m>n))
Output:  (a>b && z<h && x>y && r>s),(a>b && z<h && x>y && m>n),(a>b && y>=e && x>y && r>s),(a>b && y>=e && x>y && m>n),(p>q && z<h && x>y && r>s),(p>q && z<h && x>y && m>n),(p>q && y>=e && x>y && r>s),(p>q && y>=e && x>y && m>n)
```